# melt a data.table with a column pattern

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I have a `data.table` that looks like this:

```
id A1g_hi A2g_hi A3g_hi A4g_hi
1  2      3      4      5
...
```

I would like to `melt` this table so that it looks like this:

```
id time hi
1  1    2
1  2    3
1  3    4
1  4    5
...
```

I attempted something like this:

```
melt(dtb, measure.vars = patterns("^A"), value.name = "hi", variable.name="time")
```

which does not give me what I would like. Do I need to resort to string splitting here or are there native `data.table` functions that do this?

Comment: time is a factor there, so you can just convert it to an integer? fyi base reshape gives you exactly what you want `reshape(dd, dir = 'long', idvar = 'id', varying = list(2:5), v.names = 'hi')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I raise my glass to @rawr who apparently understands the base-R `reshape`-function. For me it is an eternal mystery, despite many efforts at understanding its documentation and many efforts at solving problems with it. Despite my general disdain for the hadleyverse efforts at "simplifying" (but for me obfuscating) R by universal "nonstandardization", I find his invention of the `reshape2::melt`-function to be a great aid in efficient manipulation.

```
require(reshape2)
> melt(dat, id.var="id")
  id variable value
1  1   A1g_hi     2
2  1   A2g_hi     3
3  1   A3g_hi     4
4  1   A4g_hi     5
> str(melt(dat, id.var="id"))
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id      : int  1 1 1 1
 $ variable: Factor w/ 4 levels "A1g_hi","A2g_hi",..: 1 2 3 4
 $ value   : int  2 3 4 5
```

So:

```
> dat2[[2]] <- as.numeric(dat2[[2]])
> dat2
  id variable value
1  1        1     2
2  1        2     3
3  1        3     4
4  1        4     5
```

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest an easy `dplyr`+`tidyr` solution.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt <- as.data.table(read.table(text = "id A1g_hi A2g_hi A3g_hi A4g_hi
1  2      3      4      5", header = T))

dt %>% gather(time, hi, -id) %>% mutate(time = extract_numeric(time))

  id time hi
1  1    1  2
2  1    2  3
3  1    3  4
4  1    4  5
```

Comment: No need for that `as.data.table(read.table(...))` stuff. Just do `fread("id A1g_hi A2g_hi A3g_hi A4g_hi\n1  2      3      4      5") %>% gather(time, h1, -id) %>% mutate(time = extract_numeric(time))`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, @Ananda, I've tried to use `fread` with specifying `text =` parameter and got an error, and then used syntax with `read.table`